# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded when loading an xlsx file

Tags: java, garbage-collection, out-of-memory, apache-poi, xssf

I understand what the error means, that my program is consuming too much memory and for a long period of the time it is not recovering.

My program is just reading 6,2Mb `xlsx` file when the memory issue occures.

When I try to monitor the program, it very quickly reaches 1,2Gb in memory consumption and then it crashes. How can it reach 1,2Gb when reading 6,2Mb file?

Is there a way to open the file in chunks? So that it doesn't have to be loaded to the memory? Or any other solution?

Exactly this part causes it. But since it is a library, shouldn't it be handled somehow smartly? It is only 200 000 rows with only 3 columns. For future, I need it to work with approx. 1 mil records and more columns...

CODE:

```
  Workbook myWorkBook;
        Sheet mySheet;
        if (filePath.contains(".xlsx")) {
            // Finds the workbook instance for XLSX file
             myWorkBook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
            // Return first sheet from the XLSX workbook
             mySheet = myWorkBook.getSheetAt(0);
             myWorkBook.close(); // Should I close myWorkBook before I get data from it?
        }
```

Comment: How much memory are you giving the program? How many rows is in the Excel file? It's a horrible format and even the actual Excel application chokes easily when you've got enough rows. The library can't outsmart the stupidity of the file format.

Comment: Sounds like one huge Excel file. It's not like you're loading 6.2 MB of flat text data.

Comment: It is around 200k rows, but I need it to work with around 1mil. rows...

Comment: Excel was never meant to be used for those sizes. Your project has ill-conceived requirements.

Comment: I would disregard the advice given by Kayaman. I tried to follow this advice, but it seems wrong. Especially "Since the data is XML, you can use StAX to effectively process the contents." I started with the assumption that Microsoft would put all the data into one file, sort of like what happens in a CSV file, but instead, Microsoft gives us a file with values that point at a different file that contains strings. How to match them up? That is what the Apache classes are for. How can one scan one file to find something in the other file without holding all of one file in memory?

Comment: I think this might be a more useful answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11118703/java-lang-outofmemory-exception-while-reading-excel-file-xlsx-using-poi .

Comment: As the answer I linked to says, just getting rid of this one line can help a lot: fis = new FileInputStream(savedFile);

Comment: When I used a File instead of a FileInputStream, I no longer faced the OutOfMemoryError.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you wish to work with large XLSX files, you need to use the streaming `XSSFReader` class. Since the data is XML, you can use StAX to effectively process the contents.

Here's (one way) how to get the `Inputstream` from the xlsx.

```
OPCPackage opc = OPCPackage.open(file);
XSSFReader xssfReader = new XSSFReader(opc);
SharedStringsTable sst = xssfReader.getSharedStringsTable();
XSSFReader.SheetIterator itr = (XSSFReader.SheetIterator)xssfReader.getSheetsData();
while(itr.hasNext()) {
    InputStream sheetStream = itr.next();
    if(itr.getSheetName().equals(sheetName)) {  // Or you can keep track of sheet numbers
        in = sheetStream;
        return;
    } else {
        sheetStream.close();
    }
}
```

The elements are `<row>`, and `<c>` (for cell). You can create a small xlsx file, unzip it and examine the XML inside for more information.

Edit:
There are some [examples](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/examples/src/org/apache/poi/xssf/eventusermodel) on processing the data with SAX, but using StAX is a lot nicer and just as efficient.

Comment: thank you. So when I get the InputStream, I need to create my own xlsx chunks from it?

Comment: I mean, what do I do with the sheetStream after that? Do I have the data which is in the file? I've never read xlsx file with an InputStream so I have no idea what to expect.

Comment: Ok so I get XML, I just don't understand the part with the unzip it... but ok, it's just my lack of knowledge. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: How could I know that XLSX is a zip file? Are all not flat files zip?

Comment: I meant are all non flat files zips?.

Comment: Thanks a lot, aren't you also providing an education lessons?

Comment: Apache POI has some examples for using SAX to parse XLSX files - https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/examples/src/org/apache/poi/xssf/eventusermodel - you might want to update your answer with pointers to that to help

Comment: I tried to follow this advice, but it seems wrong. Especially "Since the data is XML, you can use StAX to effectively process the contents." Processing an XML file is easy but what do you get? I started with the assumption that Microsoft would put all the data into one file, sort of like what happens in a CSV file, but instead, Microsoft gives us a file with values that point at a different file that contains strings. How to match them up? That is what the Apache classes are for. How can one scan one file to find something in the other file without holding all of one file in memory?

Comment: Kayaman, what is the point of using XSSFWorkbook or XSSFReader except that we are trying to get data from an Excel spreadsheet which is in XML format? Unless I misread you, your advice amounts to "Just treat this like a generic XML file." But that doesn't help. Merely iterating over XML in a lazy way is easy -- getting any useful data out of the XML is the hard part. The POI libraries understand the structure of the Excel files, that is why we use them. Using generic Stax parsers means we lose the relationships that the POI code tracks for us.

Comment: Kayaman, I believe this is what causes the OutOfMemoryError: "since even with a File there will be a FileInputStream internally." The XSSFReader seems to do poorly when given a FileInputStream, exactly because it expects a File and converts that internally to a FileInputStream. The external FileInputStream, that I created, is what caused the OutOfMemoryError in my code. When I got rid of the FileInputStream and simply used a File, then the OutOfMemoryError disappeared and my code was suddenly able to build and consume very large Excel files.

Comment: Everyone should read this answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11118703/java-lang-outofmemory-exception-while-reading-excel-file-xlsx-using-poi

Comment: At the very least, people should try that solution first, before trying anything else. It has the virtue of simplifying one's code.